# WebBrowser iframe not displays when using HttpWebRequest (navigate with own proxy)

Tags: c#, html, winforms, iframe

I use Winform WebBrowser to load an website. The website is contains an iframe. The URL here:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe

When i use `Navigate()` method to load that URL. The WebBrowser displays a texteditor and an iframe.

I want to load the website via a proxy defined by my application and then inject that data into the Web Browser control.

When i try to use `HttpWebRequest` to load the website, like this:

```
    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe");

    HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();

    webBrowser1.DocumentStream = myResponse.GetResponseStream();
```

The WebBrowser is also display an html's texteditor, but the iframe is not displayed. It just show me the iframe's URL. 
[image]
Why the WebBrowser not display the iframe contents ? While the HTML,CSS,JS still work, but the Iframe not ?

**I use HttpWebRequest instead of Navigate(), because I want to use many Proxy to load an web page. !**

Comment: Loading a document into the WebBrowser isn't the same as navigating in it. Is there a reason you want to use HttpRequest instaed of Navigate?

Comment: Because i want to use proxy.

Comment: You can set a proxy to WebBrowser by changing the registry to change the proxy on IE.

Comment: Is it another way faster ? As I use HttpWebRequest or HttpClient, I can use many proxy setting. If i have to change the IE proxy, i seem to be slower :(

Comment: The speed it takes to change the proxy in the registry is 0.1% next to the time it takes to make the network request. But it does force you to manage the threads so you only use one proxy at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are pumping the HTML stream into the browser. This is like doing an AJAX call then using javascript's `document.write` to write the contents to the document.

The issue with this is that the document URL is actually `about:blank` so any page that is loaded that has a relative url for an iframe will be `about://domain.com/path/to/iframe-page.html` and not `http://domain.com/path/to/iframe-page.html`

**EDIT**

So if the page you want to load is defined by you then just use absolute URLs. Otherwise it wont work.

Comment: Is it's any solution to change it to http://domain.com/path/to/iframe-page.html ?

Comment: The solution is to use webBrowser1.Navigate()

Comment: If the page you want to load is defined by you then just use absolute URLs. Otherwise it wont work.

Comment: If the page i want to load by me. I have to use HttpWebRequest to load the page. And it still isn't show the iframe :(.

Comment: You might be better off getting the http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/ project and modifying it to support proxies...

Comment: OMG. I understood !. It show the URL because it's not an Absolute URL. I need the append the full domain name to the URL.

Many thanks my bro !!!!!